# Make alert appear depending on select option

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
<h1 id="welcomehowareyou">How are you today, ?</h1>
<select name="mood" id="mood">
<option value="" disabled selected>How are you?</option>
<option value="m1">I'm doing great, thanks!</option>
<option value="m2">I'm fine, but could be better.</option>
<option value="m3">I feel absolutely terrible today.</option>
<!--<input type="submit" value="Done!"/>-->
</select>
<p></p>
</div>
```

How do I make a different alert (doesn't matter if PHP or JavaScript; which ever is easiest) appear when they select an option?

Also, when they click ok to the option, how do I make that re-direct them to a different link?

Comment: Start here: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/o4h0hhy5/)

You'll have to use the onchange listener for the `<select>`..So, the `<select>` should be as follows

```
<select name="mood" id="mood" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="" disabled selected>How are you?</option>
<option value="m1">I'm doing great, thanks!</option>
<option value="m2">I'm fine, but could be better.</option>
<option value="m3">I feel absolutely terrible today.</option>
<!--<input type="submit" value="Done!"/>-->
</select>
```

and the script that is used is as follows

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mood").value;
    alert(x);
}
```

This works with pure Javascript. No need for jQuery.

**UPDATE**

As @LyeFish mentioned in his comments you can code it like the one in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/o4h0hhy5/1/)..

Here the `<select>` is as follows

```
<select name="mood" id="mood" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>How are you?</option>
    <option value="m1">I'm doing great, thanks!</option>
    <option value="m2">I'm fine, but could be better.</option>
    <option value="m3">I feel absolutely terrible today.</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript for this will be

```
function myFunction(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
function myFunction(val) {
        alert(val);
        window.location.href = "http://google.co.in/";
    }
```

Comment: I'd pass `this` to the function, but other than that +1.

Comment: Amazing! That's the simplest solution I've seen! +1

Comment: Do you possibly know this? When they click ok to the alert, how do I make that re-direct them to a different link?

Comment: I've done that now. It's funny.. all the other threads I've seen, the answers seem to be long and complicated. Yours is simple and gets to the point though.

Comment: One more thing.. how would I delay the popup box from appearing until the user clicks the submit button?

Comment: I think you'll have to do all these in `<form>` and specify a php page as action for the form and do all these functions in the specified page..And dont forget to specify the method as post.

Comment: See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post) as an example..

Answer (score 1):

You can call your `JavaScript function` in `onchange evenet` , as follows

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" >
        <h1 id="welcomehowareyou">How are you today, ?</h1>
        <select name="mood" id="mood" onchange="alert(this.value);window.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
            <option value="" disabled selected>How are you?</option>
            <option value="m1">I'm doing great, thanks!</option>
            <option value="m2">I'm fine, but could be better.</option>
            <option value="m3">I feel absolutely terrible today.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!--
        You can write JS function to do as per your requirement and call the function in onchange event.
        Here it is alerting the selected value and redirecting to http://google.com. 
        You can redirect to different website also using conditional statement.
    -->
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to detect the change event of the select, and then view the elected option.

Like that:

```
$('#mood').on('change', function() {
   //alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
    switch(this.value){
        case "m1":
            alert("option 1");
            break;
        case "m2":
            alert("option 2");
            break;
        case "m3":
            alert("option 3");
            break;
    }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qpwhz6h/

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `$` function or an `.on()` method.

Comment: If you open the fiddle link, you can see the used framework, Jquery.

Comment: That's not helpful if the OP isn't using jQuery. Nothing in the question suggests that he is.

Comment: ok, i would learn for the next time, but my answer it's a possible solution